# Build a complex type from Union type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to build a type with two layers from a flat union type

Here's my code:

```js
type TextVariants =
  | {
      size: 'tiny'
      // available variants for this size
      variants:
        | 'regularNormal'
    }
  | {
      size: 'super'
      // available variants for this size
      variants:
        | 'regularNone'
    }

type TextSizesProps = {
  [k in TextVariants['size']]: {
    css: Object
    variants: {
      [v in TextVariants['variants']]: Object
    }
  }
}

const textSizes: TextSizesProps = {
  tiny: {
    css: {
      fontSize: '$tiny',
    },
    variants: {
      // Here TS is complaining about missing "regularNone" but shouldn't
      regularNormal: {
        lineHeight: '$normal',
        fontWeight: '$regular',
      },
    },
  },
  super: {
    css: {
      fontSize: '$super',
    },
    variants: {
      // same
      regularNone: {
        lineHeight: '$none',
        fontWeight: '$regular',
      },
      },
    },
  },
}
```

I have different names for each text size, and I need it to be recognized

Here's a link for the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhAewBqBDATgSxQO2AZygF4AoKKAHygG9Sy68MAvCALigHJgNsR3a6oAN3RZceFvwEUOaCAHMArgBt0AOQD2aALYolfAQF9alGlKgNmbdngWQ0%20qcMw58Es2UrtZilWg3YIBzIjYlBIWARgAGUmCDwABTR1MAJCaloAbQBrKG4IxFRnMQzrWPYAXXK2UzoAYzxxKAB5ACMAKwha4EknUVd0swzBXOx85BEXPBLeyYqq5vbO7sNaIxDa9Ww8YChgSJjmRrhEA7jE5NSB3e4Qasl6xpqBADNN6NirABIuHnYAGkkBgBAhmYjuZm8yjUmh0SnB7iU3AgAAkIBg5AALYBfbAw3T-SQvN4AdTRmOxHE%20kN8BLMQMBwKg9LINjs8LID3ZdFeuFOX1ZEHsjOCwqEEzBVwE1OhAS5AkRAVR6KxOM2gVFRNwpOVFPYVPkUKFhKZGpNDNWAIMQA)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please provide some sample input and expected output. It's hard to guess from an incomplete/ not working type to what is actually expected to be valid or invalid.

Comment: @Mushroomator thanks, I guess it's more easier to understand now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try it like this:

```
type TextSizesProps = {
  [V in TextVariants as V["size"]]: {
    css: Object
    variants: {
      [v in V["variants"]]: Object
    }
  }
}
```

Creating a mapped type out of `TextVariants['size']` and then again out of `TextVariants['variants']` will lead to a union which allows all variants for all sizes.

But if you map over the different `TextVariants` you can store each variant inside `V`. `V` now represents a specific variant and can be used to access the variants `variant` and `size` properties.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhAewBqBDATgSxQO2AZygF4AoKKAHygG9Sy68MAvCALigHJgNsR3a6oAN3RZceFvwEUOaCAHMArgBt0AOQD2aALYolfAQF9alGlKgNmbdngWQ0%20qcMw58Es2UrtZilWg3YIBzIjYlBIWARgAGUmCDwABTR1MAJCaloAbSQobgjEVGcxKBQCJAyAIgsIcoBdGrZTOgBjPHEoAHkAIwArCCbgSSdRV3SzDMEc7Cgy8qGXPFr6jp6%20gcNaIxCm9Ww8YChgSJjmNrhEY7jE5NTRg%204QBskWtsaBADMd6NirABIuHnYABpJAZgQI5mJHmZvMo1JodEooe4lNwIAAJCAYOQAC2Av2w8N0QMk70%20AHVMTi8RwfjDfMSzKCQWCoEyyDY7EiyM8uXQPrgLr8ORB7CzgmKhCJ5ryyHS4QEZXQUQEMVjcfidoEJaTcBS1dT2LT5LDRSTWdrzcyNkA)

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to it, you can change the definition of the `TextVariants` type to be an object type so you can iterate the keys in the `TextSizesProps` type.

For example:

```
type TextVariants = {
  tiny:
    | "regularNormal";
  super:
    | "regularNone";
}

type TextSizesProps = {
  [K in keyof TextVariants]: {
    css: Object;
    variants: {
      [V in TextVariants[K]]: Object;
    }
  }
}
```

or to allow for adding more fields in the future:

```
type TextVariants = {
  tiny: {
    variants: 
      | "regularNormal";
  };
  super: {
    variants:
      | "regularNone";
  };
}

type TextSizesProps = {
  [K in keyof TextVariants]: {
    css: Object;
    variants: {
      [V in TextVariants[K]["variants"]]: Object;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this is not the direct solution for my problem, but I like this way, and the code is more clean. Since I'll not opt this as a solution, I'll adopt your first suggestion in my code. Thanks!